# How to show the underlines for "navigation key (hotkey)" in Context Menu when right click?

Tags: hotkeys, context-menu

##### problem

For some reason, Google Chrome (or any other software in general) doesnt show the underlines for **"navigation key (hotkey)"** when you right click.

As the graph shows:

[Right click menu - Compare](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBri7.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### solution

###### soln1

simply press `alt + shift + right click`,

then the underlines for "navigation key" will show up in the `context menu` (<sub><sup>-- the `pop up menu when you right click`</sup></sub>).

- the point is to have `alt` pressed down (as in many application does, press `alt` will show the "navigation key")
- But this may not work in some cases, since physically pressing `alt` on your keyboard may terminate the `context menu`.
- the order matters, `alt` should be first -- `alt + shift` not `shift + alt` (no idea why)

###### soln2

use AHK to simulate a `alt` key being pressed down.

```
SendInput, {LAlt Down}
```

then you right click to bring up the `context menu`.